# Dissolve polygons using clustering

Tags: clustering, dissolve

The attached vector file contains thousands of individual polygons (a byproduct of the underlying raster image). The result of using polygonize function in qgis. My intent is to dissolve the polygons into few continuous polygons using clustering or some other prudent algorithm. Alternately not sure if i could make changes to raster file.

[image: Vector file - Polygons dissolve]

Comment: In essence, you want to remove the tiny single-"pixel" classes and merge them into their neighbors? Say, what should the few continuous polygons represent? Please add this to your question.

Comment: You could resample the raster to a coarser grid.